# Split a workbook to separate files with template with a macro

Tags: vba, excel

I need a macro to split my data from one Excel file to few others. It looks like this:

```
     UserList.xls

User    Role    Location
DDAVIS  XX       WW
DDAVIS  XS       WW
GROBERT XW       WP
SJOBS   XX       AA
SJOBS   XS       AA
SJOBS   XW       AA
```

I need, to copy data like this:

```
     WW_DDAVIS.xls 

User    Role     
DDAVIS  XX
DDAVIS  XS

     WP_GROBERT.xls
User    Role
GROBERT XW

     AA_SJOBS.xls
User    Role
SJOBS   XX
SJOBS   XS
SJOBS   XW
```

I need every user, to have his own file. The problem appeared when I was told that the files need to be filled using template (template.xls). Looks the same, but data in the source file starts in cell A2, and in the template file from cell A8.

To copy data without template I used this code:

```
Public Sub SplitToFiles()

' MACRO SplitToFiles
' Last update: 2012-03-04
' Author: mtone
' Version 1.1
' Description:
' Loops through a specified column, and split each distinct values into a separate file by making a copy and deleting rows below and above
'
' Note: Values in the column should be unique or sorted.
'
' The following cells are ignored when delimiting sections:
' - blank cells, or containing spaces only
' - same value repeated
' - cells containing "total"
'
' Files are saved in a "Split" subfolder from the location of the source workbook, and named after the section name.

Dim osh As Worksheet ' Original sheet
Dim iRow As Long ' Cursors
Dim iCol As Long
Dim iFirstRow As Long ' Constant
Dim iTotalRows As Long ' Constant
Dim iStartRow As Long ' Section delimiters
Dim iStopRow As Long
Dim sSectionName As String ' Section name (and filename)
Dim rCell As Range ' current cell
Dim owb As Workbook ' Original workbook
Dim sFilePath As String ' Constant
Dim iCount As Integer ' # of documents created

iCol = Application.InputBox("Enter the column number used for splitting", "Select column", 2, , , , , 1)
iRow = Application.InputBox("Enter the starting row number (to skip header)", "Select row", 5, , , , , 1)
iFirstRow = iRow

Set osh = Application.ActiveSheet
Set owb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
iTotalRows = osh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
sFilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

If Dir(sFilePath + "\Split", vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MkDir sFilePath + "\Split"
End If

'Turn Off Screen Updating  Events
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do
    ' Get cell at cursor
    Set rCell = osh.Cells(iRow, iCol)
    sCell = Replace(rCell.Text, " ", "")

    If sCell = "" Or (rCell.Text = sSectionName And iStartRow <> 0) Or InStr(1, rCell.Text, "total", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        ' Skip condition met
    Else
        ' Found new section
        If iStartRow = 0 Then
            ' StartRow delimiter not set, meaning beginning a new section
            sSectionName = rCell.Text
            iStartRow = iRow
        Else
            ' StartRow delimiter set, meaning we reached the end of a section
            iStopRow = iRow - 1

            ' Pass variables to a separate sub to create and save the new worksheet
            CopySheet osh, iFirstRow, iStartRow, iStopRow, iTotalRows, sFilePath, sSectionName, owb.fileFormat
            iCount = iCount + 1

            ' Reset section delimiters
            iStartRow = 0
            iStopRow = 0

            ' Ready to continue loop
            iRow = iRow - 1
        End If
    End If

    ' Continue until last row is reached
    If iRow < iTotalRows Then
            iRow = iRow + 1
    Else
        ' Finished. Save the last section
        iStopRow = iRow
        CopySheet osh, iFirstRow, iStartRow, iStopRow, iTotalRows, sFilePath, sSectionName, owb.fileFormat
        iCount = iCount + 1

        ' Exit
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

'Turn On Screen Updating  Events
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

MsgBox Str(iCount) + " documents saved in " + sFilePath


End Sub

Public Sub DeleteRows(targetSheet As Worksheet, RowFrom As Long, RowTo As Long)

Dim rngRange As Range
Set rngRange = Range(targetSheet.Cells(RowFrom, 1), targetSheet.Cells(RowTo, 1)).EntireRow
rngRange.Select
rngRange.Delete

End Sub


Public Sub CopySheet(osh As Worksheet, iFirstRow As Long, iStartRow As Long, iStopRow As Long, iTotalRows As Long, sFilePath As String, sSectionName As String, fileFormat As XlFileFormat)
     Dim ash As Worksheet ' Copied sheet
     Dim awb As Workbook ' New workbook

     ' Copy book
     osh.Copy
     Set ash = Application.ActiveSheet

     ' Delete Rows after section
     If iTotalRows > iStopRow Then
         DeleteRows ash, iStopRow + 1, iTotalRows
     End If

     ' Delete Rows before section
     If iStartRow > iFirstRow Then
         DeleteRows ash, iFirstRow, iStartRow - 1
     End If

     ' Select left-topmost cell
     ash.Cells(1, 1).Select

     ' Clean up a few characters to prevent invalid filename
     sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "/", " ")
     sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "\", " ")
     sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, ":", " ")
     sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "=", " ")
     sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "*", " ")
     sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, ".", " ")
     sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "?", " ")

     ' Save in same format as original workbook
     ash.SaveAs sFilePath + "\Split\" + sSectionName, fileFormat

     ' Close
     Set awb = ash.Parent
     awb.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

The problem in this one, is that I have no idea how to make name not DDAVIS.xls, but using WW_DDAVIS.xls (location_user.xls). Second problem - Use template. This code just copies whole workbook and erases all wrong data. All I need, is to copy value of the right data to this template.

Unfortunately I didn't find working code and I'm not so fluent in VBA to make it alone.

I tried other one, that worked only in half. It copied the template to every file and name it properly, but I couldn't figure out how to copy cells to the right files.

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyTemplate()
   Dim lRow, x As Integer
   Dim wbName As String
   Dim fso        As Variant
   Dim dic        As Variant
   Dim colA       As String
   Dim colB       As String
   Dim colSep     As String
   Dim copyFile   As String
   Dim copyTo     As String

   Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'dictionary to ensure that duplicates are not created
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'file scripting object for fiile system manipulation

   colSep = "_" 'separater between values of col A and col B for file name
   dic.Add colSep, vbNullString ' ensuring that we never create a file when both columns are blank in between

   'get last used row in col A
   lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   x = 1
   copyFile = "c:\location\Template.xls" 'template file to copy
   copyTo = "C:\location\List\" 'location where copied files need to be copied

   Do
    x = x + 1

    colA = Range("G" & x).Value 'col a value

    colB = Range("A" & x).Value ' col b value

    wbName = colA & colSep & colB ' create new file name

    If (Not dic.Exists(wbName)) Then 'ensure that we have not created this file name before
      fso.copyFile copyFile, copyTo & wbName & ".xls" 'copy the file
      dic.Add wbName, vbNullString 'add to dictionary that we have created this file
   End If

Loop Until x = lRow

Set dic = Nothing ' clean up
Set fso = Nothing ' clean up

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sub test()
dim wb
dim temp
dim rloc
rloc= "result files location"
set wb =thisworkbook
set  temp= workbook.open(template path)
' getting last row
lrow=wb.sheets(1).range("A1:A"&rows.count).end(xlup).row
icounter=0
for i=2 to lrow 'leaving out the header row
with wb.sheets(1)
if cells(i,1).value=cells(i,1).offset(1,1).value then
icounter=icounter+1
else
if icounter>0 then
range(cells(i,1):(cells(i,1).offset(-icounter,2)).copy
wb.sheet(8,1).pastespecial xlvalues
application.cutcopymode=false
filename=str(cells(i,1).value) & "_" & str(cells(i,3).value) & "".xls"
chdir rloc
temp.saveas(filename,xlworkbookdefault)
else
range(cells(i,1):cells(i,2)).copy
wb.sheets(8,1).pastespecial xlvalues
application.cutcopymode=false
filename=str(cells(i,1).value) & "_" & str(cells(i,3).value) & ".xls"
chdir rloc
temp.saveas(filename,xlworkbookdefault)
end if 
end if
end with
next i
wb.close savechanges:=false
temp.close savechanges:=false
end sub
```

this might work. i haven't tested the code. its a bit crude. i am also just a beginner in vba. forgive me if it contains errors.
look at the logic. if its all you want create a code from scratch yourself.

Answer (score 0):

@Sivaprasath V
Thanks, looks like it should work. I've changed it a little bit, to look better and to fix some issues

```
Sub test()
Dim wb
Dim temp
Dim rloc

rloc = "C:\LOCATION\result\"

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set temp = Workbooks.Open("C:\LOCATION\Template.xls")
' getting last row
lRow = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row 'changed xlUp for xlDown
icounter = 0      

For i = 2 To lRow 'leaving out the header row

With wb.Sheets(1)
        Range("C2").Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Offset(1, 0).Value Then 'changed offset from (1,1)
        icounter = icounter + 1

    Else
        If icounter > 0 Then
            Range(cells(i,1):(cells(i,1).offset(-icounter,7)).Copy   'error
            wb.Sheet(8, 1).PasteSpecial xlValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Filename = Str(Cells(i, 1).Value) & "_" & Str(Cells(i, 3).Value) & ".xls"
            ChDir rloc
            temp.SaveAs Filename, xlWorkbookDefault
        Else
            Range(cells(i,1):cells(i,7)).Copy                         'error
            wb.Sheets(8, 1).PasteSpecial xlValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Filename = Str(Cells(i, 1).Value) & "_" & Str(Cells(i, 3).Value) & ".xls"
            ChDir rloc
            temp.SaveAs Filename, xlWorkbookDefault
        End If
    End If
End With
Next i
wb.Close savechanges:=False
temp.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

I'm fighting with an error that i can't quite understand. In line:

```
Range(cells(i,1):(cells(i,1).offset(-icounter,7)).Copy
```

and this:

```
Range(cells(i,1):cells(i,7)).Copy
```

There is an error saying:

```
Compile error:

Expected: list separator or )
```

Can't figure out how to fix it. Code looks good for me.

@EDIT

Went around the error using new variable ("C" & i & ":" & "F" & i - icounter)
after some minor changes it worked, thanks :)